# If $k\sin x\cos x=\sin(kx)$ is an identity for all $x$, then what is the smallest value of $k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $k\sin x\cos x=\sin(kx)$ is an identity for all $x$, then what is the smallest value of $k$?

I tried analyzing the domain and range of the sine and cosine functions, and how this identity came to be but I could not conceptualize this problem. Any help to understand this would be appreciated

Comment: k is an integer?

Comment: Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 6):

If $|k|>2$ then:

$$|k\sin(\pi/4)\cos(\pi/4)|=\left|\frac{k}{2}\sin(\pi/2)\right|=\left|\frac{k}{2}\right|>1\ge|\sin(k\pi/2)|$$

So $|k|\le 2$. Note that $k=-2$ works because:

$$-2\sin(x)\cos(x)=-\sin(2x)=\sin(-2x)$$

So $k=-2$

Comment: ah ok you just give a counterexample! That's a nice way.

Comment: Can you provide all possible values of k such that $sin(kx)=k sin x cos x$?

Answer (score 2):

For $k\neq 0$, $k\sin x\cos x$ is zero at, and only at, all integer multiples of $\pi/2$; as it's equivalent to a sinusoid, that sinusoid necessarily has period $\pi$. We conclude that $k$ can be only $2$, $-2$, or $0$.

Determining the *smallest* $k$ is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

We know that for $k=2$

$$\sin (2x)=2\sin x \cos x$$

but for $k=1$, in general

$$\sin (x)\neq \sin x \cos x$$

and for $k=-2$

$$\sin (-2x)=-2\sin(2x)=-2\sin x \cos x$$

therefore for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ the minimum value seems to be $k=-2$ (refer to [Zachary Selk's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2866409/505767) answer for the counterexample for $|k|>2$).

Comment: This doesn't prove that $k=-2$ is the minimum though.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Yes, indeed I wrote just it seems. I was looking to your answer.